# Equivalent of saying "I think, ..." for when you're not 100% sure of what you say?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, nuances

皆さん、こんばんは！

What would a good equivalent for saying "I think, ..." be in 日本語?

Like, if you wanted to say "I think (it's) not from here" and started with...

```
ここからじゃないですな。
```

What could you do to this, or similar sentences, to add a aura of admitted uncertainty to it?

Comment: Don't say ですな unless you're deliberately trying to sound like a stereotypical old, upper-class gentleman. The normal way of saying it is ですね.

Comment: Really? Then why do I keep hearing 男の日本人 youtubers use it often? or are they just slurring ね ?

Comment: They may be trying to be humorous. Heaven knows English Youtubers have odd speech habits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

> 「～～ような気{き}がする/します」
>
> 「～～ではないか（な）と思{おも}う/思います」
>
> 「～～では（or じゃ）ないでしょうか」

Very informally, quite a few people have been using the following patterns for the last couple of decades:

> 「～～、みたいな？」
>
> 「～～かな、みたいな？」

Your sentence:

> 「ここからじゃない**ですな**。」

is ***not*** incorrect, unnatural or anything.  It is a good one.  With the 「です**な**」- ending, however, practically all native speakers would think that that would be said by ***older*** people (and quite possibly by a fictional character).

Comment: Dd you put the な from my sentence into your examples, or are they all generic?

Comment: Would 〜〜ではないと思います be correct? I usually just assume to add　と思います when I need to say "I think", but it looks like my assumption might be wrong.